# closing ActiveRecord connection on a dead thread

Tags: activerecord, rails-activerecord

If a thread dies or I have to kill a thread that is using an ActiveRecord connection, how do I make sure that the ActiveRecord connection is returned back to the pool? I keep getting errors like

`DEPRECATION WARNING: Database connections will not be closed automatically, please close your
database connection at the end of the thread by calling`close`on your
connection.  For example: ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close`

but how do I make sure this happens on a thread that dies unexpectedly, or one that call Thread.kill on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure connection closing =)

```
Thread.new do
  begin
     raise "foo"
  ensure
     begin
        if (ActiveRecord::Base.connection && ActiveRecord::Base.connection.active?)
           ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
        end
      rescue
      end
  end
end
```